# How to find argument of beautiful soup.find() function?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to learn scraping using Python, and I tried writing my first little script.

The problem I have is that after running the script I have many different errors, and when I comment the strings with errors other errors arise...

Here's part of the code I tried to write:

```
titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()
prezzo = soup.find('li', class_='in-feat__item--main in-detail__mainFeaturesPrice').text.strip()

elemento_locali = soup.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip()
elemento_superficie = soup.find('li', aria-label='superficie')

print("Elemento Locali:", elemento_locali)
print("Elemento Superficie:", elemento_superficie)

locali = elemento_locali.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip() if elemento_locali else None
superficie = elemento_superficie.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip() if elemento_superficie else None
```

I am trying to scrape this page: https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/centro/?criterio=rilevanza
(no, can't afford those houses, I need to get much better at Python before! :D )

The errors I get are:

> expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?
> related to elemento_superficie = soup.find('li', aria-label='superficie')

Then I comment out that line and:

> line 42, in 
> titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

And so on and so on...

Am I doing something wrong relative to the argument? Or maybe it's something else?

---

Here is the whole code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import requests

dati_immobili = []

with open('quartieri.txt', 'r') as file_quartieri:
    info_quartieri = [line.strip() for line in file_quartieri.readlines()]

with open('quartieri.txt', 'r') as file:
    voci_list = [line.strip() for line in file.readlines()]



url_base = 'https://www.immobiliare.it/vendita-case/milano/'


driver = webdriver.Safari()


for voce, info_quartiere in zip(voci_list, info_quartieri):
    # Scorrimento su pagine successive
    url = f'{url_base}{voce}/?page='
    page_num = 1


    while True:

        url_completo = f'{url}{page_num}'
        driver.get(url_completo)

        try:

            soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

            # Estrai i dati desiderati
            titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()
            prezzo = soup.find('li', class_='in-feat__item--main in-detail__mainFeaturesPrice').text.strip()

            elemento_locali = soup.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip()
##            elemento_superficie = soup.find('li', aria-label='superficie')

            print("Elemento Locali:", elemento_locali)
            print("Elemento Superficie:", elemento_superficie)

            locali = elemento_locali.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip() if elemento_locali else None
            superficie = elemento_superficie.find('div', class_='in-feat__data').text.strip() if elemento_superficie else None



            # Aggiungi i dati a una lista
            dati_immobili.append({
                'Titolo': titolo,
                'Prezzo': prezzo,
                'Locali': locali,
                'Superficie': superficie,
                'InfoQuartiere': info_quartiere
            })

            # Incrementa il numero di pagina
            page_num += 1

        except NoSuchElementException:
            break

driver.quit()

# Converti la lista di dati in un DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(dati_immobili)

# Esporta il DataFrame in un file Excel
df.to_excel('dati_immobili.xls', index=False)
```

Comment: `soup.find('li', aria-label='superficie')` is invalid python, because `aria-label` is interpreted as `aria minus label`.

Comment: Oh thank you @JohnGordon! So should I change the way I write it or avoid to use it altogether?

Comment: Use the `attrs=` argument: `soup.find('li', attrs={"aria-label": "superficie"})`

Answer (score 0):

`titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()` resulting in NoneType error means there was no  element with class ".in-reListCard__title" on the page you're scraping.

If this element doesn't always exist on the page you're scraping, you could add a check for `None`, so that you would skip or do something else in case wanted element does not exist.

```py
titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()
if titolo is not None:
   titolo_text = titolo.text.strip()
```

Otherwise you might be scraping a different page than the one you think you are. Might be also that the html tag or class is actually different on the page than the one you have hardcoded in your code.

Comment: Thank you Mixanik, unfortunately this code (I tried something similar before and now your code which seems definitely better) returns this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ale/Desktop/ScraperImmobiliare.py", line 42, in <module>
    titolo = soup.find('h1', class_='in-reListCard__title').text.strip()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'